# Where to put fixtures in custom plugins?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, symfony-1.4, fixtures

I have a custom plugin in Symfony 1.4 and I want to add some fixtures to database. Where shall I put the file `fixtures.yml` ?

Or shall I put it in `ROOTPROJECT/data/fixtures/fixtures.yml` ? Actually I want to keep data in the plugin as far as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also put them in ROOT/plugins/yourPlugin/data/fixtures/fixtures.yml.

Comment: It dose not work when `./symfony doctrine:data-load`. Do I need to configure something?

Comment: If the plugin is installed and enabled, it should load the fixtures.

Comment: The plugin was generated with `sfTaskExtraPlugin` and installed properly, but is not working, is not loading the fixtures form `ROOT/plugins/myPlugin/data/fixtures/fixtures.yml`. However if I copy them in `ROOT/data/fixtures/fixtures.yml` the loading is ok. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm you enabled the plugin in your ProjectConfiguration.class.php?